# MongoDB and complex query on ordered arrays

Tags: mongodb, collections, find

I've the following entity persisted on `mongo` in a `users` collection:

```
{
    "fullname": "Luke Tomson",
    "nicknames": [
        {
            "name": "lukeone",
            "created": ISODate("2011-05-18T19:42:56.411Z")
        },
        {
            "name": "magicluke",
            "created": ISODate("2012-01-12T19: 42: 56.411Z")
        },
        {
            "name": "superluke",
            "created": ISODate("2012-03-27T19: 42: 56.411Z")
        }
    }
]
}
```

How do I get the **last** nickname `name` for a user whose `fullname` is `"Luke Tomson"` ? And more specifically, how do I retrieve in the mongo shell a specific index (the first or the last) of a sorted array that was sorted upon a specific field (in this case, `created`).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields), the second object passed to a `.find` is a selection of what portions of the object you want returned.

So, what you want is basically:

```
db.users.find({"fullname": "Luke Tomson"}, {"nicknames": { $slice: -1 } });
```

Though you might also want to return the `_id` if there are multiple "Luke Tomson"s in your DB and you need to uniquely identify them.

Comment: And is there a way to actually retrieve the user who's last nickname is "superluke" ?

Comment: If you query an array element with a non-array value, it will return all records where at least one of the records contains the specified value. If you really need only the records where ``superluke`` is the last nickname, then you can fall back to the ``$where`` table-scan-style query. The string you pass to ``$where`` should be a single Javascript statement that evaluates to a boolean and ``this`` is a single MongoDB record. ``db.users.find({$where: "this.nicknames[this.nicknames.length-1].name == 'superluke'"})``. You may be able to chain ``find``s to reduce the scan size.

Comment: Oh, by the way, [this page is your friend](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries). It's very dense, but I got everything I know about MongoDB from either this page or the other I linked to you. (And experience playing with the node-mongodb-native library.)